# Nested Loop Over Same List Increasing Nests

Tags: foreach, nested, nested-loops

I want to have nested loops over the same list in increasing number of nested loops.  The inner loop will call a method with a params list.

```
    public void MainMethod()
    { 
        var list = new List<MyObject>();
        //Populate list...
        foreach (var item1 in list)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in list)
            {
                MyMethod(item1, item2);
            }
        }
        foreach (var item1 in list)
        {
            foreach (var item2 in list)
            {
                foreach (var item3 in list)
                {
                    MyMethod(item1, item2, item3);
                }
            }
        }
        // and so on...
    }

    private void MyMethod(params MyObject[] items)
    {
       
    }
```

Is there a way to simplify this?

**Update**: One improvement is to add the call to the method of the previous nested loops inside of the last nested loop.

```
    foreach (var item1 in list)
    {
        foreach (var item2 in list)
        {
            foreach (var item3 in list)
            {
                MyMethod(item1, item2, item3);
            }
            MyMethod(item1, item2);
        }
    }
```

My final nested loop will be 11 levels deep, so I was thinking that there might be a cleverer way to do this.

Comment: doesn't make sense. MyMethod expects array, by you not passing array, furthermore you are passing same item

Comment: MyMethod takes in a params array.  I'm passing in (item1, item2) the first time and (item1, item2, and item3) the second time.  The params turns those into arrays.